# Showing the domain of a URL

Tags: python, optimization, url

I have such a method which takes a URL, such as http://twitter.com/ttt or twitter.com/dasd, and should show its domain with http: http://twitter.com and name twitter

```
def show_domain(url):
    sites = {
        'twitter': ['http://www.twitter.com/', 'twitter'],
        'facebook': ['http://www.facebook.com/', 'facebook'],
        'pininterest': ['http://www.pininterest.com/', 'pininterest']
    }

    if sites['twitter'][0] in url:
        link = sites['twitter'][0]
        brand = sites['twitter'][1]
    elif sites['facebook'][0] in url:
        link = sites['facebook'][0]
        brand = sites['facebook'][1]

    else:
        link = sites['pininterest'][0]
        brand = sites['pininterest'][1]
    return link, brand
```

Is there way to optimise this code?

Comment: Have you considered using the `urlparse` module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking/list unpacking to write :

```
if sites['twitter'][0] in url:
    link, brand = sites['twitter']
elif sites['facebook'][0] in url:
    link, brand = sites['facebook']
else:
    link, brand = sites['pininterest']
return link, brand
```

Now, the data structure you are using is a bit akward because you don't use the key at all. Instead of mapping string to list of strings, you could have a list of list of strings. Even better, you could use list of tuple of strings :

```
sites = [
    ('http://www.twitter.com/', 'twitter'),
    ('http://www.facebook.com/', 'facebook'),
    ('http://www.pininterest.com/', 'pininterest')
]

if sites[0][0] in url:
    link, brand = sites[0]
elif sites[1][0] in url:
    link, brand = sites[1]
else:
    link, brand = sites[2]
return link, brand
```

Now, this seems to be begging to be written with a loop

```
for (link, brand) in sites:
    if link in url:
        return link, brand
return None # or anything you like
```

Comment: but it local variables link, brand are unused, pycharm says

Comment: @user2424174 then it is a bug in pycharm, because they are being returned, so used.